# How to break a loop at a certain point in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2008, breakpoints

I have a `for`-loop which runs for 1000+ times over a string array.

I want to have my app break when one of the strings matches a certain term.
So I can walk through my code from that point.

Now, I know I can add a piece of code that looks for this and a breakpoint when it hits, but is there not a way to do this in the debugger?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to your code

1. create a breakpoint
2. right click on the red dot on the left
3. select *condition*
4. put something like *i == 1000*

or

at the middle of your loop

write

```
if (i == 1000){
  int a = 1;
}
```

and break over int a = 1;

The second method looks more like garbage, but I find it easier and faster to do

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can in the debugger.  It's called a "conditional breakpoint."  Basically, right click on the red breakpoint and go to the "condition" option.

A quick google turned [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sye83ce.aspx) and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308469) up:

P.S.  The last one is VS 2005, but it's the same in 2008.

Comment: Google (bing?) are good, but it's also nice to have StackOverflow.com with all these little details too.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio you can set a [conditional breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?#breakpoint-conditions):

- Set a breakpoint at the point you want to break as normal.
- Right click on the red dot in the left margin and
  select "Conditional Breakpoint...".
- Type an expression that evaluates to `true` when you want to break,
  (e.g. i == 1000, or MyString = "hello world")